# Jasper Reports with C++ possible or painful?

Tags: c++, jasper-reports

I've briefly looked at using [Jasper Reports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports) as a reporting engine.  However it's all in Java and everything else we have including our server/client architecture, in memory data model, etc is all in C++.  Does anyone have any experience with wrapping JasperReports and calling it from C++ or do they have an interface which provides some sort of API to do this?

Alternately does anyone know a good reporting package designed in or for C++?

As side note we don't use SQL syntax or traditional data sources as the data model is accessed through a generic query interface and is capable of being persisted to any database technology Oracle, SQL Server, Sysbase, etc, or any combination thereof so the emphasis is more on the ability to dynamically format and generate "sexy looking" reports and although the web support would be nice that is not a necessity either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From how you describe your environment, I'd not go into Jasper Reports, unless some corner somewhere in your company has already used it.

Comment: yeah that's kind of the way I was leaning ... I may end up just creating my own reporting framework.